# Unable to access a Polymer form element

Tags: forms, polymer

Attempting to apply this https://garstasio.github.io/ajax-form/components/ajax-form/

The problem I keep running into is that the `document.getElementsByTagName("form")` is not working for me.  I can grab the `<h1>` tag just fine but not the form element.

```
<link rel="import" href="/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="test-ajax">
  <template>

   <h1>test-ajax</h1>
   <form action="test">

   <label for="test">
     <input type="text" name="test">
   </label>

   </form>

  </template>
  <script>`
    Polymer('payment-request', {
      ready: function() {
        console.log('ready');
        var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
        console.log('form', form);
      }
    });
  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

Any ideas how to grab the form element?

Answer (score 1):

polymer elements are not in the main document

in order to access the elements one needs to do either

`this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];`

or put an id on the form `<form id="my-form"></form>` and then do

`this.$["my-form"]` to access the form